# Appium with Webdriverio is not waiting for the element

Tags: javascript, android, automation, appium, webdriver-io

I've just setup Appium with Webdriverio and I am having a trouble waiting for the element.
Session ends as soon as app is opened, and I can see from Appium logs that it waits **0ms** for the element.

This is my test file **login.test.js**:

```
const welcome = require("../../pageObjects/welcome.page");

describe("Login", () => {
  it("Verify user can login", () => {
    driver.setImplicitTimeout(10000); // tried with implicit wait
    driver.pause(3000); // and with explicit wait
    welcome.signInBtn.click();
  });
});
```

**welcome.page.js** file:

```
class WelcomePage {
  /**
   * Define Elements
   */

  get signInBtn() {
    return $("~Sign in");
    
  }
}

module.exports = new WelcomePage();
```

**package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "appium_js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.16.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.16.13",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.16.13",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.16.13",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.16.13",
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.16.13"
  }
}
```

**wdio.conf.js** file:

```
let { join } = require("path");

exports.config = {
  
  runner: "local",
  port: 4723,
  path: "/wd/hub",
  
  specs: ["./test/specs/**/*.js"],
 
  maxInstances: 1,
  
  capabilities: [
    {
      platformName: "Android",
      "appium:deviceName": "Pixel XL API 31",
      "appium:app": join(process.cwd(), "./app-dev-debug.apk"),
    },
  ],
  
  logLevel: "info",
  
  
  bail: 0,
  
  
  baseUrl: "http://localhost",
  
  waitforTimeout: 0,
  
  connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
  
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  
  services: ["selenium-standalone"],

  
  framework: "mocha",
  
  
  reporters: ["spec"],

  
  mochaOpts: {
    ui: "bdd",
    timeout: 60000,
  }
};
```

**Appium logs**:

```
[W3C (10484f32)] Calling AppiumDriver.findElement() with args: ["accessibility id","Sign in","10484f32-220b-4a22-ae39-9b7c6ff9adfb"]
[BaseDriver] Valid locator strategies for this request: xpath, id, class name, accessibility id, css selector, -android uiautomator
[BaseDriver] Waiting up to 0 ms for condition
[WD Proxy] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8201/wd/hub/session/0b87b7c0-9b19-48ce-9e6e-02c6d5cc8d08/element] with body: {"strategy":"accessibility id","selector":"Sign in","context":"","multiple":false}
[HTTP] --> DELETE /wd/hub/session/10484f32-220b-4a22-ae39-9b7c6ff9adfb
[HTTP] {}
[W3C (10484f32)] Calling AppiumDriver.deleteSession() with args: ["10484f32-220b-4a22-ae39-9b7c6ff9adfb"]
[BaseDriver] Event 'quitSessionRequested' logged at 1642100255280 (19:57:35 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time))
[Appium] Removing session 10484f32-220b-4a22-ae39-9b7c6ff9adfb from our master session list
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 session
[UiAutomator2] Deleting UiAutomator2 server session
[WD Proxy] Matched '/' to command name 'deleteSession'
[WD Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /] to [DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8201/wd/hub/session/0b87b7c0-9b19-48ce-9e6e-02c6d5cc8d08] with no body
```

Not sure why it doesn't wait for the element as I've tried with implicit and explicit waits? Maybe it has do to with the **driver**?

Comment: Did you try setting a value other than 0 to waitforTimeout property in your config file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `waitforTimeout` in your driver capabilities for implicit waits for all your global driver executions.
For further reference on this, please refer to this documents,

https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts/#waitfor-timeout

https://building.niche.com/appium-automated-app-testing-f8f6f9682061